# How to get the participant number in data with repeat instances

Tags: r

```
   library(data.table)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    participant.index = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,7)
    repeat.instance = c(1,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,1,1)
    fruits.eaten = c("apple","apple", "grapes", "oranges", "oranges", "pineapple",
                     "pear", "pineapple","banana", "pear")
    gender =c("male", "female", "male", "male", "female",
              "male","male","male","male","female")
    mydata = data.table(participant.index,repeat.instance,fruits.eaten,gender)
```

## Identify total number of males and females

```
    dt1 = mydata %>% filter(mydata$repeat.instance == '1')
    dt1[, .N, by = gender]

#>    gender N
#> 1:   male 4
#> 2: female 3
```

I did this using filter function and creating a different data.table. But when dealing with big data, with multiple such columns where the variables are same, are there any better ways to do this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn’t your current approach work with bigger datasets? What are you trying to do that’s different from your example? Can you show some of your actual data (use `dput(mydata)` or eg `dput(head(mydata, n = 25))`) and what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size does not matter too much, I notice you use both dplyr to filter and then data.table to group. You can do it in one call.

```
# using the repeat.instance == 1
mydata[repeat.instance == 1, .N, by = gender]

# perhaps more elegant as you use all unique participants
mydata[!duplicated(participant.index), .N, by = gender]
```